# Closed non-intersecting geodesics on a compact hyperbolic surface are finite

Tags: riemannian-geometry, surfaces, hyperbolic-geometry, geodesic

I recently came across this exercise.

Let $S$ be a closed orientable surface of genus strictly greater than one and let $g$ be a Riemannian metric on S with constant negative curvature. Then, given any infinite family of simple closed geodesics on S, there are at least two geodesics in this family that intersect in a point (in other words, a family of closed simple geodesics that are disjoint two by two must be finite).

So far, I only managed to prove that, if $(\gamma_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a sequence of simple closed geodesics, $\gamma_n : S^1 \to S  $, then
$$
\inf_{n,m\in\mathbb{N}}\mathrm{d}(\gamma_n,\gamma_m)=0,
$$
where $\mathrm{d}$ is the distance induced by $g$ on $S$. This infimum must be zero because, for any $t\in S^1$, the sequence $(\gamma_n(t))_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is contained in $S$, which is compact, so it admits a converging subsequence $(\gamma_{n_k}(t))_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$, which is a Cauchy sequence, and thus the equality above holds. Now, my (qualitative) idea is that the limit point is very near to all the geodesics in the sequence (for $k$ sufficiently big) and, since on a surface there is not much room, the geodesics are forced to meet in a point. Anyway, I do not how to make it rigorous nor if my idea is correct.

I am also aware of some basic results concerning hyperbolic manifolds, for example Cartan-Hadamard Theorem or the one to one corrispondence between closed geodesics and free homotopy loop classes, but I am not really familiar with them, so I do not know how to apply these theorems.

Any hint will be really appreciated.

Comment: So, what is exactly your question? Are you asking for a solution of this exercise?

Comment: @MoisheKohan I was asking if anyone knows how to prove that on closed orientable hyperbolic surfaces a family of closed simple geodesics that are disjoint two by two must be finite.

Comment: If you have a finite family of pariwise disjoint closed geodesics and you cut the surface along these geodesics, what can you say about the surface(s) you get (how many connected components, their genus...)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose that $S$ is a closed connected oriented surface of genus $g\ge 2$ and $L$ is a 1-dimensional submanifold in $S$ such that the complement $S-L$ contains no components which are annuli or disks. Prove (using the Euler characteristic) that the number of components of $L$ is $\le 3g-3$.

Now, if $S$ is equipped with a Riemannian metric of negative curvature, then a closed geodesic in $S$  cannot be null-homotopic and two such geodesics cannot be homotopic unless their images are the same. Use these observation to conclude that if $L\subset S$ is a submanifold each component of which is geodesic then the number of components is at most $3g-3$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. However, I need a little clarification: what do you mean exactly when you say "$S - L$ contains no annuli and disks"? You mean that each connected component of $S - L$ must not be homeomorphic to a disk or an annulus or that in $S - L$ there are no subset homeomorphic to a disk or an annulus?

Comment: I mean no component of this complement is a disk and no component is an annulus.